# Setup KeePass on Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope)

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-9.04, keepass

Has anyone manage to setup KeePass 2.x on Ununtu 9.04? I looked but could not figure out how to install it, plus i didn't find any tutorials on this.

Also if you installed it, how does it work, does it crash a lot ? I saw that a lot of people have been having problems on Ubuntu instalations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty) and KeePass Portable 2.0 works for me. It also appears to work for others from the later responses on this thread: [[SOLVED] Mono & KeePass 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=916806). People who initially complained about crashes have reported it to be working for them on the final Jaunty release.

As for installation, get the latest [Portable Keepass Professional edition](http://keepass.info/download.html) and follow the project instructions on [running KeePass under Mono](http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#mono). If you have the mono components required, you should be able to unpack the zip and just run the KeePass executable.

The forum post linked to above mentions that you need the *libmono-winforms2.0-cil* and *libmono-winforms1.0-cil* packages in addition to the core mono package. However, I only have *libmono-winforms2.0-cil* on my system and Keepass 2.0 works fine on it.